# How to get showing plain text using javascript from browser

Tags: javascript

I am showing a webpage using web browser(chrome).

How to get exactly the showing text using javascript in web browser when I click a mouse. (not all text in document(html) )

Comment: Can't understand a thing you're trying to ask here !!

Comment: I suggest showing an example of what you are trying to achieve and an example of some code you have written to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from you question what text you're trying to show using javascript. 
If you're looking for a way to launch a function when a user clicks something you can use the following syntax:

```
"<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>"
```

As for showing text you can use "alert()" to show text as a popup, for example, you can use the following:

```
<button onclick="alert('show some text');">Click here</button>.
```

I hope this helps.